# Can't read file with open()

Tags: c

Today I've a problem in C: I open a file on read-only with a function, but I can't read the buffer without segfault. I don't know where it comes from...

My function:

```
char * read_file(char * file)
{
    struct stat buff;
    char * buffer;
    int size = 0;
    int last = 0;
    int nb = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    if (nb != -1) {
        stat(file, &buff);
        size = buff.st_size;
        buffer = malloc(size + 1);
        last = read(nb, buffer, size);
        buffer[last] = '\0';
        close(nb);
        return (buffer);
    } else
        return ("fail");
}
```

I call this function here:

```
int error_handling(char * file)
{
    if (my_strstr(read_file(file), "fail") == 0) {
        return verify_file(read_file(file));
    }
    return 84;
}
```

My main function:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        if (my_strstr(argv[1], "-h") != 0)
            help_flag();
        if (error_handling(argv[1]) != 84) {
            connect_parent();
            return 0;
        } else
            return 84;
    } else if (argc == 3) {
        if (error_handling(argv[2]) != 84) {
            return 0;
        } else
            return 84;
    }
    return 84;
}
```

Unrelated but here is my `my_strstr` function:

```
char *my_strstr(char *str, char const *to_find)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        while (str[i + j] == to_find[j]) {
            if (to_find[j + 1] == '\0') {
                return (&str[i]);
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I know that it fits well in my first condition after I put a printf, so it does manage to open the file...

Error from valgrind:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x404078
at 0x404078: ??? (in /workspace/navy/navy)
by 0x401274: error_handling (main.c:24)
by 0x4012ED: main (main.c:35)
```

Main.c:24 is the line

```
if (my_strstr(read_file(file), "fail") == 0) {
```

from my `error_handling` function

Comment: What value does `size` get set to? (Use your debugger or a printf to check).

Comment: Unrelated, but you are returning an alloced buffer which should be freed when you could read and a pointer to a litteral string which should not be freed when you cannot. This is a poor design because it will be hard to correctly free the allocated array. Better to return NULL to denote a read error. (Calling `free(NULL);` is safe)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson segfault is appearing before I can check size

Comment: Look up the documentation of `stat()` and what is says about its second parameter. Who provides the memory? And which sizes shall it have?

Comment: @busybee stat is called with the address of buff, a 'struct stat`, as it should be.

Comment: Show the call, including how string `file` is set.

Comment: @FlorianKamps if it fails before stat, then it fails on open. Does open actually return? Perhaps there's a problem wih the `file` string.

Comment: I think it fail on `stat()`, I've updated my post with the valgrind error

Comment: @stark here's my call, I modified my question

Comment: Assuming `stat` was successful, and `malloc`, and `read`, the `read_file` function on first glance looks okay.  But it would be wise to actually check that all of those functions actually succeed instead of assuming they do.

Comment: You still don't show how the string `file` is set, though. Is it a valid string? Is it a valid filename?

Comment: Should `my_strstr` reset `j=0` each iteration of outer loop?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I'm 100% sure the file is okay, because nb return a positive integer

Comment: I don't use built-in function because that's forbidden by my school

Comment: I've verified all those function, that's works and I'm sure it come from `read_file` function

Comment: So I've updated my post with the -g3 on compilation with valgrind

Comment: The valgrind output looks like there was a bad jump, which is strange. Time to use a debugger, I think: find out exactly where you first get an unexpected value or behavior.

Comment: Aside from the memory leaks, it runs cleanly for me under valgrind with a small sample file.  How large is the file you're working with?  Also, can you post the code in the form of a [mcve], i.e. a self-contained block of code that still shows the problem that others can also run and see the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

So, I had a global variable in one of my files called `stat`. Changing his name solved my problem.